# How to see who liked a video post on instagram's desktop website

Tags: python, selenium, web, instagram

I am trying to scrape Instagram using python selenium. Specifically I want to scrape the likes of an account's posts. The problem is with the video posts. In the desktop website the video post only display the views and when you click the views it only shows the number of likes and not the accounts that liked that video post. [This image shows the only thing that is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwajj.png). What can I do to access the likes of video posts?

Comment: Can you manually get to this data?

Comment: what do you mean manually? I cannot access the people who liked the video post neither by browsing the website and clicking in some place nor by looking through the source code of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments if the data is not in the source of the page you will not be able to scrape this data.

Comment: Yeah it seems like it. Either way I used the Instaloader module for this task. It's very strange that the desktop website does not have likes posted on video post.